# How to fix "org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: null" [Mule/CXF]

Tags: mule, cxf

I'm setting up a mule app with cxf web service, following the [offical document](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/building-web-services-with-cxf), have already tried both jaxws and simple mode, get the same errors.

I'm using AnypointStudio 6.6 with MuleESB 3.9.0 CE.

This is the interface and class code.

```
package jcoservice;

public interface HelloWorld {
    String sayHi(String name);
}
```

```
package jcoservice;

public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {

    public String sayHi(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

and the mule flow xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf"
    xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata"
    xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
        host="0.0.0.0" port="8881" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />
    <flow name="jcoserviceFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
            path="hello" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <cxf:simple-service serviceClass="jcoservice.HelloWorld" />
        <component class="jcoservice.HelloWorldImpl" />
    </flow>
</mule>
```

When I'm accessing localhost:8881/hello, it should give the wsdl description content, but I got error like this.

```
<soap:Envelope><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Fault occurred while processing.</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

and the console:

```
WARN  2019-05-06 16:50:29,845 [[jcoservice].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://jcoservice/}HelloWorld has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: null
    at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleInvoker.invoke(MuleInvoker.java:131) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58) ~[cxf-api-2.7.19-MULE-002.jar:2.7.19.MULE-002]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37) ~[cxf-api-2.7.19-MULE-002.jar:2.7.19.MULE-002]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107) ~[cxf-api-2.7.19-MULE-002.jar:2.7.19.MULE-002]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) ~[cxf-api-2.7.19-MULE-002.jar:2.7.19.MULE-002]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) ~[cxf-api-2.7.19-MULE-002.jar:2.7.19.MULE-002]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.sendThroughCxf(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:436) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.sendToDestination(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:302) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.process(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:167) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.config.FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.process(FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.java:49) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:99) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:110) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:99) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.construct.DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.process(DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.java:55) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:74) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:99) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:48) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:99) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:52) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:99) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:57) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:48) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:74) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:74) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$3.process(AbstractPipeline.java:232) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.routeEvent(HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.java:73) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase$1.process(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:73) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase$1.process(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:60) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:36) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:114) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:41) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MuleMessageProcessingManager.processMessage(MuleMessageProcessingManager.java:32) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListener$1.handleRequest(DefaultHttpListener.java:135) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.java:100) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:119) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.access$100(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:31) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:142) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.SimpleMethodDispatcher.getMethod(SimpleMethodDispatcher.java:97) ~[cxf-rt-core-2.7.19-MULE-002.jar:2.7.19.MULE-002]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionInvokationHandler.invoke(ReflectionInvokationHandler.java:90) ~[cxf-api-2.7.19-MULE-002.jar:2.7.19.MULE-002]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.getMethod(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleInvoker.invoke(MuleInvoker.java:80) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    ... 108 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied your code exactly and it works fine.

You are missing the ?wsdl query param in your url.

In a browser or any GET request use URL: http://localhost:8881/hello?wsdl

Without ?wsdl you get the error you described.